# Removing a keystone jack from the wall plate

Tags: electrical, cord-and-plug, ethernet

I am about to install some ethernet cord with jacks I know I will upgrade in the future. However, I'd like not to waste the jacks that will be replaced. How will I be able to remove them from the wall plate without damaging them? Is it possible?

Comment: Depends on which companies products....

Comment: I have pulled the wires and reused tons of jacks. If they work great! If not time for a new one. 10 based T old slower never a problem. 100 based T works most of the time. Fiber needs new index gell but works almost 100% with more gel

Comment: @Ed Beal I'm pulling the jacks out of the wall plate, is the main issue. I know how to pull wires from the jack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  It is possible.

Keystone jacks almost always have two angled ledges.  One stationary upon which the keystone pivots (Red below), and the other spring loaded which 'snaps' into place (Green below).[image: keystone sideview]

Jam a straight blade in at the blue angle to push the green tab in, and pry it out.

In 3by1 and 3by2 outlet plates, it's normal that they are too close together to take out in any old order.  You have to start from one end and work to the other of the plate.

Comment: Two of the plates that will be upgraded will be 3 by 1; in both cases only one of the jacks will be upgraded. So the one that will eventually be replaced should go at the top?

Comment: That depends what is more important to you. The ease of the future work. Or putting them in an order that makes the most sense to the end user. It is not cataclysmically more difficult too eject all three later and put them back in whatever order you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to not to risk marring or deforming the face of the assembly. Remove the screws from the plate and lift it off the box or frame, then release the locking tabs from the rear using a thin blade.

Answer (score 0):

when I recently did it, it seemed better to cut off the part of the plate holding the jack.  The plates are much cheaper than jacks, so to reduce risk of breaking the springy part of the jack, I did it that way.